# How to execute an script within an conditional statement using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to execute the script within an conditional statement, I have also tried to use the script within an function but its not working

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')

if df1['id_number'] != NaN:
  cross = df1[['id_number']].merge(df2[['identity_no']], how='cross')
  cross['match_acc'] = cross.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.id_number, x.identity_no), axis=1)
  df1['match_acc'] = df1.id_number.map(cross.groupby('id_number').match_acc.max())
```

Is there any other way to execute the script under the given condition. Can we use the conditional statement by creating an function.

```
def conn(x):
  cross = df1[['id_number']].merge(df2[['identity_no']], how='cross')
  cross['match_acc'] = cross.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.id_number, x.identity_no), axis=1)
  df1['match_acc'] = df1.id_number.map(cross.groupby('id_number').match_acc.max())
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: Can you post the exact error traceback? It looks like you are comparing a series of values with a scalar `NaN`. You have to specify if you want *all* values to be != NaN or *any*.

Answer (score 0):

In `if df1['id_number'] != NaN:` you are comparing a series to a single value (scalar) of `NaN`. This will create a boolean array of `True`/`False` values. You need to specify whether you want any of those values to be `True`, or all of the values:

```
if df1['id_number'].notna().any(): # any one value has to be != NaN
```

or

```
if df1['id_number'].notna().all(): # all have to be != NaN
```

Comment: Using the 2nd line it gives the error : NameError: name 'NaN' is not defined

Comment: @NKJ I assumed that `NaN` would be defined in your code, since you are using it. Edited.